# how to Show deleted comments in admin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to put the list of deleted comments in the admin section. IsDelete capability also has a comments section. The code works fine, but when I put the where condition, the output value is zero and no comments are displayed.

```
public ShowCommentUsersForAdminViewModel GetRemovedCommentByAdminSearch(int pageId = 1, string filter = "")
        {
            //lazy load enable with IQueryable
            IQueryable<BlogComment> result = _context.BlogComments
                .Include(c => c.Blog)
                .Include(c => c.User);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
            {
                result = result.Where(u => u.Comment.Contains(filter) || u.User.UserName.Contains(filter) || u.Blog.BlogTitle.Contains(filter));
            }
            //show Item In Page
            int take = 10;
            int skip = (pageId - 1) * take;


            ShowCommentUsersForAdminViewModel list = new ShowCommentUsersForAdminViewModel();
            list.CurrentPage = pageId;
            list.PageCount = (result.Count() / take) + 1;
            list.BlogComments = result.Where(c => c.IsDelete).OrderBy(u => u.CreateDateComment).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

            return list;
        }
```

Comment: .Where(c=>c.IsDelete) is used twice.

Comment: Wherever I put it, the result will be zero. I corrected the code and put where at the end, but the result is still zero.

Comment: You can debug this in Visual Studio and get the actual SQL being generated by EF. This might help you figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Check if you have configured [global query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) for `IsDeleted == false`. If yes, then [ignore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#disabling-filters) it for this query.

Answer (score 0):

yes I used this code

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<ProductComment>().HasQueryFilter(b => !b.IsDelete);
```

Reviewed the code again, and used IgnoreQueryFilters() problem solved.
thanks Ivan Stoev